# Accessing the user password in user table from Keystone database in correct form(String)

Tags: java, openstack, keystone

```
import java.sql.*;
public class userRegistration {

   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/keystone";
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "cusat123";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT name,id,password FROM user";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next()){

         String first = rs.getString("name");
         String last = rs.getString("id");
         String pwd = rs.getString("password");

         if("siju".equals(first))
         {
          if("cusatse".equals(pwd))
          {
              System.out.println("login ok");
          }
         }
         System.out.print(" username: " + first);
         System.out.println(", id: " + last);
         System.out.println(", password: " + pwd);
      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}

}
```

The Output is

> username: siju, id: 0d2809092a1e41c485181b07f8ac62ae
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$JHmpeyx13IDIJdgJ$zFGji3SJPQ4Dx3pz6BWnIXmkVvpZNmHxMfj8qN2DOQ2K6pR5Vl/UNfjo00HJwNXRgXxEhly6N6Hf6MTaMb1d21
>    username: glance, id: 47bcfb1392514dc5b890bfb14186663d
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$yDvqf1kBnvcTldCH$DGKrrqY3mavByeM8xtqF8AaXEFiViapwHLo14WnTIE4z0N.IiCJ96lIxtmqfDKqYp2lxCQkFpff63Wh8.z2du/
>    username: nova, id: 5504658950fa47239fa476e895111f5a
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$YQe7qgAKC3UiLBkM$pFd.VCf2U6PeJnx2ejPGkW04tHq63o0fb9RiUjJTztiouH.d7UhqRmwA0aVZb6j/O..XDnhV9U4MLBnbW315Z0
>    username: admin, id: 6a6bae538bd749bb8f6388ec5f3c2707
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$.6.GubHpPpkZrk5J$RtRAI3Xd9.eAWKoQCMtfVf6jNok.n6zCcqFWlV/1x0RWjLAxd29/Jm9OjtNUNtK8JqJPjl0.lgyuHc1ZJVYIY0
>    username: swift, id: bce9ad99e4ad44988203180080ac022a
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$OWbwnCWLbCEPSwed$.UbZQD4WLnjzM4n2qkSMjqpP8IIXNMtKNQuW3oqNdfvUof1/qYVGtnEcONPphmXBbJMlOZOkQqTnTrFC03UU70
>    username: demo, id: d059821f33fa498b979b7b1539f00274
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$X8MyyrjduXoeHC1F$e6Dc2k4bUz9YnnWY/rx0ECXW95mZhAdV8EDNnY9waLmuAXfVThME7g.V2rirhCt6WkRA4yr1jQlB9D2lTT0iL1
>    username: sunil, id: e57a4c4bce984cbebf2a4f9babd42983
>   , password: $6$rounds=40000$/mrUJI0OIe6TOVWx$z4fOjo4hRk55sI2MbE/rrkqKiPrRvY9WdNMfhsitvmeIHccO8FjeqWS7dM3KUNt0giM1Cx4ayduSQcJxKlFyP/
>   Goodbye!

1.The problem is the password is in different form.

2.Can i access the password from the Keystone database in a correct string form...???

Comment: Do you mean you wish to get the unencrypted password?

Comment: you actually need to decrypt the password as you might be encrypting it during , saving the password into database !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't decrypt password FROM mysql, because password is hashed by using md5 hash algorithm, which is not an encoding algorithm.